# Why don't databases have good full text indexes

Tags: sql, database, solr, full-text-search, nosql

Why don't any of the major RDBMS systems like MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc. have good full text indexing support?

I realize that most databases support full text indexes to some degree, but that they are usually slower, and with a smaller feature set. It seems that every time you want a really good full text index, you have to go outside the database and use something like Lucene/Solr or Sphinx.

Why isn't the technology in these full text search engines completely integrated into the database engine? There's lot of problems with keeping the data in another system such as Lucence, including keeping the data up to date, and the inability to join the results with other tables. Is there a specific technological reason why these two technologies can't be integrated?

Comment: Questions about why certain people make certain design decisions are really not a good fit for this communication platform, because answers are based mostly on guesswork and opinion.

Comment: I don't know about MySQL or Oracle, but at least DB2 and SQL Server do have a full text search feature in the more recent versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDBMS indexed serve a different purpose. They are there to offer the engine a way to optimize access to the data, both by the user and by the engine itself (to resolve joins, check foreign keys, etc...). As such they are really not a functional data structure.

Tools like full-text search, tag clouds may be very useful for enhancing the user experience. These serve only the user and applications. They are functional, and require real data structures... secondary tables or derived fields... with, typically, a whole lot of triggers and code to keep these updated.

And IMHO... there are many ways to implement these technologies. RDBMS producers would have to maybe choose some tech over another... for reasons that have nothing to do with the RDBMS engine itself. That does not really seem their job.